# In which version of .NET the yield return syntax was added

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious in which version of C# was the `yield return x` syntax added and which versions of .NET support it?

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFoo(List<object> values)
{

    foreach(var item in values)
    {
        yield return item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `yield` was added in C#/.NET 2.0.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_2.0

Comment: [The only new keyword in 2.0 was "yield", and switching to yield return meant that C# 2.0 would compile all C# code without change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2006/03/08/why-yield-return-rather-than-yield/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information in the [What's New in C# page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/).

It says:

> **C# 2**, Visual Studio .NET 2005:
>
> Anonymous methods, generics, nullable types, **iterators/yield**, static classes, and covariance and contra variance for delegates.

Yield return is a compiler feature which [generates a custom IEnumerator implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) under the hood so no specific .NET framework is required for it. It only requires generics and the generic `IEnuerator<T>` available so anything **.NET 2.0 and above** will work.

Answer (score 1):

Custom iterators (`yield return`, `yield break`) were added in C# 2.0, which shipped with .NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005.